# Incompatible types: 'tValidPos' and 'tPos'

Tags: delphi, casting, delphi-2010

In the following code, I get the errors as commented:

```
function ToPos : tValidPos;
type
  tPos      = (poAboveCenter , poAboveLeft  , poAboveRight);
  tValidPos =  array [Low (tPos)..High (tPos)] of tPos;
const
  validPos : tValidPos = (poAboveRight, poAboveLeft, poAboveCenter);
var
  i, pos : tValidPos;
begin
  i := Low (validPos); // Incompatible types: 'tValidPos' and 'tPos'
  pos := validPos [i]; // Incompatible types: 'Enumeration' and 'tValidPos'
  Result := i; 
  for i := Low (validPos) to High (validPos) do
    if validPos [i] = pos then begin
      Result := validPos [i];
      Break;
    end;
end;
```

I can't figure out what's wrong, since

1. `i` and `validPos` are both of type `tValidPos`
2. same applies for `pos` and `validPos`

If I use brackets like `pos [0] := validPos [i]` I still get "Incompatible types: 'Enumeration' and 'tValidPos'"

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Looking at your code it's hard to imagine what you're trying to do? Can you explain what you want to do with that code? Also, the function result "tValidPos" where is it declared?

Comment: In the previous question (the one you deleted) I explained that the code you're posting makes no sense, and asked you when you reposted to please explain *in your question text* what you were really trying achieve. There are several problems in the code you've posted, but it's hard to tell you how to fix them if we don't know what you want to do in the first place. Once again, please [edit] your question and provide an explanation of what your code is supposed to be doing, so we have an idea of what to do to help you find an answer.

Comment: I'll try to explain:

The original function receives a tComboBox and a list
of valid positions. That list is of tValidPos that,
in turn, is an array of tPos. tPos is an enumerator
that lists all possible positions. The list of valid
positions is variable. Each element to position has
it's valid positions. The function returns the
correspondent tPos for each tComboBox.ItemIndex.
I posted that coded for simplifying purposes but
eventually, I think I wasn't succeeded.

Comment: I have a working version of that function, but I had
to use tPos for the assignments.

Comment: What intrigues me, is although 'i' and 'validPos' are
both of type 'tValidPos', the compiler doesn't accept
the assignment. Can you explain this?

Besides this, I can't make an assignment like 'i':=validPos[0]'.
Compiler claims that I must use an enumertaor instead
of an ordinal value, meaning that I can't use the
tComboBox.ItemIndex value for the assignment. Have you any
idea how can I achieve that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally found the solution. It was quite simple indeed.

Since is not possible to use an ordinal value to index an array of enumerators, the way to achieve this was by iterating based on `tComboBox.ItemIndex` and, at the same time, fetch the next `validPos` using `Succ` function.

```
type  tPos      = (po1, po2, po3, po4, po5, poNil);
   tValidPos =  array [Low (tPos)..High (tPos)] of tPos;
const  validPos : tValidPos = (po1, po4, poNil, poNil, poNil, poNil);
 .........
function ToPos (const aComboBox: tComboBox; validPos: tValidPos) : tPos;
var p, pos : tPos ;
    i      :  Byte;
begin
  p := Low (ValidPos); // initialize with first validPos

  for i := 0 to aComboBox.ItemIndex do begin
    pos := validPos [p]; // current validPos

    if  pos = poNil then begin // not validPos?
      pos := Low (ValidPos); // first validPos
      Break;
    end;

    if Succ (p) <= High (validPos) then // next p is in range?
      p := Succ (p) // next validPos
    else
    begin
      pos := Low (ValidPos); // first validPos
      Break;
    end;
  end;

  Result := pos; // return corresponding validPos
end;
```

There's only one restriction: `validPos` elements must be 
ordered as in `tPos`.

Note: I just forsaw the "indexing" solution and that's the
reason for getting stacked. After giving it a good thought,
the real solution came up.

Answer (score 1):

> i := Low (validPos); // Incompatible types: 'tValidPos' and 'tPos'

`i` is an array, but `Low(validPos)` returns a single ordinal value, not an array.  Hense incompatible types.

> pos := validPos [i]; // Incompatible types: 'Enumeration' and 'tValidPos'

`pos` is also an array, but `validPos[i]` is a single ordinal value, not an array. Hense incompatible types.

For what you are attempting to do, `i`, `pos`, and `Result` all need to be declared as `tPos`, not `tValidPos`.

Comment: `i [0] := validPos [0]; // Incompatible types: 'Enumeration' and 'tValidPos'`

Comment: @user2383818: If you changed `i` to be a `tPos` like I suggested, then `i[0]` is not a valid statement because `i` is not an array anymore, so you can't index into it. If you don't understand the difference between an ordinal value and an array, you need to stop what you are doing and go read a good tutorial on programming basics.

Comment: 1 - No, in the statement above, 'i' still is a 'tValidPos'.
That's why I don't understand why I can't assign the element [0] of
array 'validPos', to the elemnt [0] of the array 'i'.

Comment: 2 - You were disrecpectfull based on a wrong pressumption. Even if
youre pressumtion was right, that doesn't give the right to be
disrecpectfull.